# TSQL - Advice on how to break up OR conditions in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need advice on how to break up this query so it's not so slow. I've been reading up on EXISTS and UNION but I'm not sure how they can be used in this situation. LineA/B/C are all nvarchar(max) and I can't change the join to be on something other than text. Has to be line this, unfortunately.

```
UPDATE n SET AddressID = a.AddressID
FROM #NewAddress n
JOIN dbo.Address a
    ON (a.[LineA] = n.[LineA] OR (a.[LineA] is null AND n.[LineA] is null))
    AND (a.[LineB] = n.[LineB] OR (a.[LineB] is null AND n.[LineB] is null))
    AND (a.[LineC] = n.[LineC] OR (a.[LineC] is null AND n.[LineC] is null))
WHERE n.Processed = 0
```

Any ideas on how to UNION or EXISTs this query? This seems to be a pretty common join condition I'm encountering

I'm not sure how to post a query plan, but it's really small like this

```
SELECT 0% <---- Hash Match (Inner Join) 75% <------- Clustered Index Scan 0%
                                            <------- Clustered Index Scan 25%
```

None of these rows are indexed as they are nvarchar(max). I can't index dbo.Address either

-- RESOLVED

I added an index to the Processed column in #NewAddress. Apparently, that was the slow part

Comment: Can `LineA` really be null? If `LineA` means `AddressLine1` I'm highly skeptical of your data integrity...

Comment: Yes, it can be null. Very sketchy I know. This is the hand I've been dealt

Comment: Are there any indexes already on dbo.Address? Can you give us some idea of the numbers of records on each table? Do you actually want all the fields from both tables in your select?

Comment: Are there other fields except lines `A` through `C`? Do you need them selected?

Comment: There's a primary key on Address (AddressID), but I'm only provided the LineA/LineB/LineC values and I have to match it up. The rows are nvarchar(max). I'm actually updating #NewAddress with the Address.AddressID value

Comment: Can you give us some idea of the numbers of records on each table? Do you have the privileges necessary to create either indexes or indexed views?

Comment: I don't have the privileges to do so, no. There's typically around 1k rows in #NewAddress and around 200k in Address

Comment: Does coalesce() yield any improvement? `on coalesce(a.LineA,'<null>') = coalesce(n.LineA,'<null>')` And what happens if the addresses match but on different lines, e.g. LineA matches LineB?

Comment: @Tim: this treats string `'<null>'` and actual `NULL` as same. See here why shouldn't you rely on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456438/how-can-i-pass-the-string-null-through-wsdl-soap-from-as3-to-coldfusion-web

Comment: @Quassnoi: not sure what you mean.  If the column value `is null` I am substituting the string `<null>` in order to be able to use the "=" operator. That is, I am also adding angle brackets as part of the string.

Comment: @Tim: What if the string actually has `<null>` in it?

Comment: @Tim - I changed to `COALESCE(a.LineB, '') = COALESCE(b.LineB, '')` for readability. This is the same as  `(a.[LineB] = n.[LineB] OR (a.[LineB] is null AND n.[LineB] is null))`, right?

Comment: Can you create an indexed view? This does not affect the original tables and does not require write or modify permission on them.

Comment: Then it would match, and I think in this particular instance the OP might actually want a truly absent value in LineA (i.e. NULL) to match the string <null> in LineB.  This programming paradigm is known as "fighting shite with shite", though some prefer "fire". :-)

Comment: user1002479: Do you have the privileges to create an indexed temporary table?

Comment: @user1002479:   COALESCE returns the first non-null value. In your case you're returning zero-length string.Would work the same. I was choosing <null> (open angle bracket n-u-l-l close angle bracket) to make the substitution of a string for a null as explicit as possible (to someone who happened upon your code). But see Quassnoi's and Mark Bannister's caveat above. In this particular case I don't think the "false positives" would matter very much. But you have to decide if you want a zero-length string present in the original data to match a NULL.

Comment: Alright. Since there are no zero-length strings present, I'm safe to use COALESCE(a.LineA, '')? Thanks. Whoever had that as the answer but deleted it, please repost it. Even though it didn't solve the issue, it helped with the readability

Comment: @user1002479 it doesn't much improve readability and it'll hurt performance if you're currently relying on indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really improve this query much without indexing, but using this syntax:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    a
JOIN    b
ON      EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  a.lineA, a.lineB, a.lineC
        INTERSECT
        SELECT  b.lineA, b.lineB, b.lineC
        )
```

you give the optimizer ability to use `MERGE JOIN` which theoretically can be more efficient.

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14946/1) (with actual `MERGE JOIN` in the plan)

Comment: The produces the same query plan, oddly. Very interesting approach though

Comment: @user1002479: try forcing another join method (replace `JOIN` with `INNER MERGE JOIN`)