# Safest way to remove argument order and provide default values at the same time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameter-passing, default-value, keyword-argument

I am trying to write Python 2.7 cod that is easier to scale by removing argument order while providing default values in the case that requirements change. Here is my code:

```
# Class:
class Mailer(object):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.subject=args.get('subject', None)
        self.mailing_list=args.get('mailing_list', None)
        self.from_address=args.get('from_address', None)
        self.password=args.get('password', None)
        self.sector=args.get('sector', "There is a problem with the HTML")
# call: 
mailer=Mailer(
    subject="Subject goes here", 
    password="password",
    mailing_list=("email@email.com", "email@email.com","email@email.com"),
    mailing_list=("email@email.com", "email@email.com"),
    from_address="email@email.com",
    sector=Sector()
```

)

I'm still new to the language so if there is a better way to achieve this, I'd really like to know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way of initialize your class:

```
class Mailer(object):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        for k in args:
            self.__dict__[k] = args[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the way you're doing it is that there is no documentation about what arguments the class accepts, so `help(Mailer)` is useless. What you should do is provide default argument values in the `__init__()` method where possible.

To set the arguments as attributes on the instance, you can use a little introspection, as in [another answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36486435/416467), to avoid all the boilerplace `self.foo = foo` stuff.

```
class Mailer(object):
    def __init__(self, subject="None", mailing_list=(),
                 from_address="noreply@example.com", password="hunter42",
                 sector="There is a problem with the HTML"):

    # set all arguments as attributes of this instance
    code     = self.__init__.__func__.func_code
    argnames = code.co_varnames[1:code.co_argcount]
    locs     = locals()
    self.__dict__.update((name, locs[name]) for name in argnames)
```

You can provide the arguments in any order if you make the call using explicit argument names, *regardless of how they're defined in the method,* so your example call will still work.