# How to let csvhelper distinguish null and empty string

Tags: csvhelper

I have such csv that only have quote for string values, and it use empty string with no quote to represent null value. For example, one line is:
`1,"",2`
for this line, the second field represents empty string. another line is:
`1,,2`
for this line, the second field represents null value.
I'm wondering if csvhelper could handle such kind of csv files.

I tried to add following line to my code but csvhelper will recognize the second field of both line as null value.
`csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<string>().NullValues.Add("");`

I want to know if there is some way to parse such kind of csv correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way with `CsvHelper` to distinguish between `String.Empty` and `null` using `1,"",2` and `1,,2`. The best you can do is to have a specific string value be your null value, such as using `"null"`.  You could then write a custom converter for your `CsvWriter` that always writes null strings as `"null"` or whatever value you want to use to indicate a `null` value.

You can find a discussion about this issue [on Github](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/252).

**Modified:** Since the string `"null"` can easily be a valid string value, I have taken @dbc's advice to encode and decode the `"null"` string so that it can make the round trip without being turned into `null`.

- `null => "null"`
- `"null" => "null(1)"`
- `"null(N)" => "null(N+1)"`

If you are looking directly at the csv file, you would need to recognize that `"null"` => `null`, `"null(1)"` => `"null"` and `"null(N)"` => `"null(N - 1)"`

```
Id,Name
1,
2,null
3,null(1)
4,null(8)
5,null(0)
```

```cs
void Main()
{
    var fileName = @"C:\Temp\NullString.csv";

    var records = new List<Foo> {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = String.Empty },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = null },
        new Foo { Id = 3, Name = "null" },
        new Foo { Id = 4, Name = "null(7)" },
        new Foo { Id = 5, Name = "null(0)" }
    };

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new NullStringConverter());
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
    }

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csvReader.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new NullStringConverter());
        csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<string>().NullValues.Add("null");
        var result = csvReader.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class NullStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "null";
            
        if ((string)value == "null")
            return "null(1)";

        if ((string)value == "null(0)")
            return "null(0)";

        // check for "null(N)"
        var match = Regex.Match((string)value,"^null\\(([0-9]+)\\)$");
        
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var number = BigInteger.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);

            return $"null({number + 1})";           
        }

        return base.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData);
    }

    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {

        if (text == "null")
            return null;

        if (text == "null(1)")
            return "null";

        if (text == "null(0)")
            return "null(0)";
            
        // check for "null(N)"
        var match = Regex.Match(text, "^null\\(([0-9]+)\\)$");

        if (match.Success)
        {
            var number = BigInteger.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);

            return $"null({number - 1})";           
        }

        return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *The best you can do is to have a specific string value be your null value, such as using "null"* -- not recommended, see [How to pass "Null" (a real surname!) to a SOAP web service in ActionScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4456438).  If you want to do this, you will need to encode the string `"null"` as well, e.g. `null` => `"null"`, `"null"` => `"null(1)"`, `"null(N)"` => `"null(N+1)"`.

Comment: @dbc I believe I understand that the string `"null"` would need to become something like `"null(1)"` and if I happened to have the string `"null(1)"` it would need to become `"null(2)"`, etc.  However, for most applications, couldn't we get by with something that is highly unlikely to be encountered, say `"[[null]]"`?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, you need some sort of string mapping that is unambiguously invertible. `XmlConvert.EncodeName()` + `XmlConvert.DecodeName()` do something similar.

Comment: *for most applications, couldn't we get by with something that is highly unlikely to be encountered* -- sure.  But it's hard to be certain about whether a given null sentinel is highly unlikely or not without knowing the precise application. `"[[null]]"` is highly unlikely for a surname but reasonably likely for a JSON encoded column.  And since people tend to blindly copy/paste code from Stack Overflow the answer might get used in apps where a given `null` sentinel is more likely than expected.

Comment: @dbc I ran into a slight problem with `"null(N+1)"`.  `"null(0)"` => `"null(1)"`, which then becomes `"null"`.  I could keep `"null(0)"` => `"null(0)"`, but then I have trouble with ulong max `"null(18446744073709551615)"` => `"null(0)"`, which then stays as `"null(0)"`.  I appear to have just changed the magic value that won't convert correctly. Now `"null(18446744073709551615)"` is the one value that won't make the round trip.

Comment: Well, that's probably OK.  Or you could use BigInteger.  Or use a less compact encoding scheme where `"null"` gets replaced with `"esc(null)"` and `"esc(...)"` gets replaced with `"esc(esc(...))"`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. Really appreciate! Unfortunately I cannot control the null value of the csv because csv is not generated by me, my code will just read from the csv. I'm wondering if there is some way to get the raw value of each column so that I can distinguish between quoted empty string and empty string. I know IParser has a RawRecord property but it will just return the whole line

Comment: I thought the same thing, but unfortunately I don't think there is a way to get the individual raw value.